# Get number of partitions in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, database-partitioning

What is the most efficient way to get the number of partitions created in the database?

I am using **PostgreSQL** API for C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you can select all the names of the table partitions:

```
SELECT
    nmsp_parent.nspname AS parent_schema,
    parent.relname      AS parent,
    nmsp_child.nspname  AS child,
    child.relname       AS child_schema
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent        ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child         ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
```

It can be used to count as well:

```
SELECT
    nmsp_parent.nspname     AS parent_schema,
    parent.relname          AS parent,
    COUNT(*)
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent        ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child     ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
GROUP BY
    parent_schema,
    parent;
```

Comment: And how do I delete the oldest partition? (The partition which was created first?)

Comment: If the lowest OID is the oldest partition, you could use MIN(child.oid) to find this partition. You can use this to find the name and schema for this table and use it to DROP this table. A stored procedure makes it a bit easier to maintain.

Answer (score 8):

Traditional partitioning is [implemented with **inheritance**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION-INHERITANCE). Every inheriting table has an entry in the system catalog [pg_inherits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-inherits.html). The number of partitions for a given parent table can simply be counted with:

```
SELECT count(*) AS partitions
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_inherits
WHERE  inhparent = 'schema.parent_tbl'::regclass;
```

The solution also works for [**declarative** partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) in Postgres 10 or later because, quoting the manual:

> Individual partitions are linked to the partitioned table with inheritance behind-the-scenes;

Related question on dba.SE:

- [Get all partition names for a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/40441/3684)